# Calling Win32 EnumThreadWindows() in C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to get a call to EnumThreadWindows working, but I always get a Wrong Parameter-Error, although my code is nearly the same as [this example on pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/enumthreadwindows.html).
I don't know why this doesn't work:

```
public static IntPtr FindMsgBoxFrom(IntPtr MainHWND)
{
    SetLastError(0);
    uint ThreadID = GetThreadID(MainHWND);
    EnumThreadWindows(ThreadID, new WNDENUMPROC(decoder.FindMsgBox), IntPtr.Zero);
    int last = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    if (last != 0)
        MessageBox.Show("EnumThreadWindows-Error:\n" + GetLastErrorString());

    return MSGHWND;
}
```

and this is `decoder.FindMsgBox`:

```
public static bool FindMsgBox(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lparam)
{
    if (IsMsgBox(hwnd))
    {
        MSGHWND = hwnd;
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
    }
}
```

What's the problem with this?

Comment: Please include your declaration of EnumThreadWindows and the WNDENUMPROC delegate. Also, if you could include more information on the error that would be useful. For example, do you get a compile time or runtime error?
There's no point in calling SetLastError from managed code.

Comment: oh im sorry I forgot that:
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(uint dwThreadId, WNDENUMPROC lpfn, IntPtr lParam);

public delegate bool WNDENUMPROC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

and I get the error when I call Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
and format it with FormatMessage

Comment: Edit your question with the new information. There's no formatting on comments so it's nearly impossible to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your EnumThreadWindows call should work fine, the problem seem to be in the

```
uint ThreadID = GetThreadID(MainHWND);
```

call; it looks like you're trying to pass window handle in there and this is not exactly what it expects to get from you, more details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683233(VS.85).aspx

I've tried to change the line above to the following code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

<...>

uint ThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId();
```

and the rest of your code worked fine for me

Also if you're looking to get thread ID for the given window handler, the code below might give you an idea on how to do it:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

public static uint GetThreadIdForForegroundWindow()
{
   IntPtr hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
   return (hwnd!=IntPtr.Zero) ? GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero) : 0;
}

<...>

uint ThreadID = GetThreadIdForForegroundWindow();
```

regards